# splitting symfony into frontend and backend servers

Tags: symfony

I currently have a symfony application that works on a single server (frontend, backend, database)

I now need to implement this application on a large customer, but he isn't allowing me to connect to the database from the DMZ. I need to implement a server inside the network that will comunicate with the database and provide the data via Web service to the appllication on the DMZ.

Is there any simple way to split my symfony application into 2 parts that would communicate via web services? One part would be the frontend, communicating to the clients, and the other part needs to be the backend, communicationg to the database. The communication between those 2 parts needs to be via web service.

The only way i can currently think of, is redoing most of my backend on the DMZ server to connect to web services instead of database, and rewriting my frontend on the network side to convert from html into web services. Is there any plugin or way to automate this, or am i stuck doing it from scratch?

Comment: Sure, make a clone of your application and use it as backend. Implement REST api into it. You can see here - can be very helpful http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest

Comment: @pavlovich Yeah, i know rest. I'm mostly using it in the app allready. But that's the hard way :) i need to rebuild a lot to get rest in there completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up implementing my own login controller, and set up the application so it can pass on all received data to either the local or remote server depending on settings. I have had to somewhat disable symfony security and implement my own though.

Not a perfect solution, but it works for now, and we have already decided to switch back-end from symfony to nodeJS in the near future, so not a problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have elegant way to solve this case, if the project is planned to work on high availability with significant load, you can think of implementing one of ESB solutions. But you have to judge on your own if its not shooting to the fly with the cannon.

Example of such elastic sollution is [WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/)

This kind of solution can broaden posibilities in any project in terms of communication between any kind of end points.

**EDIT**
You can also run Doctrine Rest Driver
https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

I think this is great solution.